# MTU test times out

Tags: networking, ping

Determined because of my home infrastructure I am better off turning off Jumbo Frames except on the switches themselves for all devices.  So everything in my house is basically set to 1500.  Doing a ping -f -l on different devices return different results though.  So if I ping two different computers on the same physical switch from a computer on another switch I get:

MCE:  1473 packets gives fragmented, 1472 down to 1463 packets gives:

```
ping mce -f -l 1472

Pinging mce [192.168.0.2] with 1472 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

That computer will show a normal ping with -f -l 1462

My encoder PC will fragment at 1473 packets but anything below that pings fine.  I think it's the Mellanox ConnectX-3 network card in the mce computer but in this computer I can't use any other 10Gbe card.  To many compatibility issues with an older system.

Any idea why there is that area of packets that doesn't show fragmentation but just fails entirely from 1472 down to 1463?  All my other computers fragment down to a certain packet size and below that ping fine.

mcuroute returns:

```
mturoute.exe mce
* ICMP Fragmentation is not permitted. *
* Speed optimization is enabled. *
* Maximum payload is 10000 bytes. *
...- ICMP payload of 1472 bytes failed. (IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT)
+ ICMP payload of 92 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 782 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1127 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1299 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1385 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1428 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1450 bytes succeeded.
+ ICMP payload of 1461 bytes succeeded.
.- ICMP payload of 1466 bytes failed. (IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT)
.- ICMP payload of 1463 bytes failed. (IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT)
+ ICMP payload of 1462 bytes succeeded.
Path MTU: 1490 bytes.
```

Comment: It might help to know which OS versions are on which device, and whether or not you're doing any 802.1Q tagging for VLANs or QoS. A packet capture certainly wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Source computer running the ping is Windows 10.  Computer with the "issue" is on Windows 8.1.  No VLANs setup or QoS.  Added mcuroute output to original post.

Comment: Can't speak for why the lack of response at those packet sizes, but might have an idea just not sure why.  In the Mellanox settings Jumbo Packet is set to 1500.  But if I do a netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces I see 1486.  Any idea why this is?  Can I just update it in Windows thru the command prompt or do I need to up something in the "GUI"?